# lualatex uses DejaVuSans ExtraLight instead of DejaVu Sans

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

LuaLaTeX does not use the correct font shape.

The following minimal example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
    This is a Test.

    \textbf{This is a Test.}

    \textsf{This is a Test.}

    \textsf{\textbf{This is a Test.}}

    \texttt{This is a Test.}
\end{document}
```

compiled with TexLive 2013 results in the following document:

[image: Result of Compilation]

Instead of using normal DejaVuSans, ExtraLight shape is embedded into the document. But the correct bold font is used.

Compiling this document with TexLive 2012, the correct fonts are used.

```
 minimal.cls    2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2013/07/28 v4582 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
  luatex.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 LuaTeX basic definition package (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
l3basics.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2013/07/24 v4565 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2013/07/21 v4564 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2013/07/09 v4521 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2013/07/24 v4576 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
  xparse.sty    2013/07/28 v4582 L3 Experimental document command parser
luaotfload.sty    2013/07/23 v2.3b OpenType layout system
luatexbase.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Resource management for the LuaTeX macro programmer
luatexbase-compat.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Compatibility tools for LuaTeX
luatexbase-modutils.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Module utilities for LuaTeX
luatexbase-loader.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Lua module loader for LuaTeX
luatexbase-regs.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Registers allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-attr.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-cctb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-mcb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Callback management for LuaTeX
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
```

**Edit:**

After a reinstallation of TexLive 2013 from a DVD everything worked as expected.

Then I updated the `luaotfload`-package (30701 -> 31286) and the error was there again.

While running LuaLaTeX I got the following message:

```
luaotfload | db : Version mismatch; expected 2.207, got 2.204
luaotfload | db : Force rebuild
luaotfload | db : Version mismatch; expected 2.207, got 2.204
luaotfload | db : Force rebuild(load luc: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/dejavuserif.luc)
```

This was repeated multiple times (for every dejavu-font on my system, as it seems) and happend every time I run LuaLaTeX.

With `luaotfload-tool --force --update -v` I rebuilt the fonts database and the next run of lualatex was without those forced rebuilds. But sadly, the output is still the same.

Comment: I get correct output both with TeX Live 2012 and 2013

Comment: The dev version of luaotfload has some tweaks to the font matching. On my machine it picks the correct fonts: http://i.imgur.com/5t61jDR.png

Comment: Works fine for me too (miktex + TL13 on windows 7)

Comment: I even deleted `luaotfload-names.lua` so that `luaotfload` had to rebuild the font names database, but the result was the same.

Comment: I reinstalled TexLive 2013 from a DVD and the problem was gone.

Sadly after I updated my TexLive installation, I face the same problem again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem was not with TexLive at all.

I reinstalled `ttf-dejavu` (I'm working on an Ubuntu-machine) and now everything works like a charm.